# observer method sales_order_place_after not executing

Tags: magento-1.8, php, event-observer

I am using magento 1.8.
I have requirement that need to save the order details in separate custom table.
for this I need to execute **saveorder** method using observer event **sales_order_place_after** But when I am clicking place order, My observer function is not executing,

My config.xml file content

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Npm_Commission>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Npm_Commission>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <npm_commission>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Npm_Commission_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>calculate_commission</method>
                    </npm_commission>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>
        <resources>
            <commission_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Npm_Commission</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </commission_setup>
            <commission_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </commission_write>
            <commission_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </commission_read>
        </resources>
        <models>
            <commission>
                <class>Npm_Commission_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>commission_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </commission>
            <commission_mysql4>
                <class>Npm_Commission_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <commission>
                        <table>commission</table>
                    </commission>
                </entities>
            </commission_mysql4>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

my observer method

```
<?php
class Npm_Commission_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
    public function saveorder($observer)
    {
        die('sales_order_place_after');
        $params = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParams();
        echo "<pre>";print_r($params);die();
    }
```

If this information is not enough, add in comment for other part of code.
And suggest any other idea for this issue, Or my faults in this code.

Thank you friends:)

Comment: it seems code you pasted is fine.please paste the whole code from your config.xml

Comment: What payment method do you use? Afaik there are a few events which don't fire with paypal

Comment: Yes, I used paypal only

Comment: @Charlie method name should be `saveorder` and not `calculate_commission` in config.xml. I bet you would have already solved it :)

Answer (score 1):

There are small issue ,in closing backet of class  Npm_Commission_Model_Observer and method name is wrong, should  `calculate_commission from saveorder` as xml define

```
<?php
class Npm_Commission_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
    public function saveorder($observer)
    {
        die('sales_order_place_after');
        $params = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParams();
        echo "<pre>";print_r($params);die();
    }
} /* it was missing */
```

Also

total code  config.xml code is (path app/code/local/Npm/Commission/etc)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Npm_Commission>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Npm_Commission>
        </modules>
        <global>

            <models>
                <commission>
                    <class>Npm_Commission_Model</class>
                    <resourceModel>commission_mysql4</resourceModel>
                </commission>
                <commission_mysql4>
                    <class>Npm_Commission_Model_Mysql4</class>
                    <entities>
                        <commission>
                            <table>commission</table>
                        </commission>
                    </entities>
                </commission_mysql4>
            </models>

            <events>
                <sales_order_place_after>
                    <observers>
                        <npm_commission>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>commission/observer</class>
                            <method>calculate_commission</method>
                        </npm_commission>
                    </observers>
                </sales_order_place_after>
            </events>
            <resources>
                <commission_setup>
                    <setup>
                        <module>Npm_Commission</module>
                    </setup>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_setup</use>
                    </connection>
                </commission_setup>
                <commission_write>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_write</use>
                    </connection>
                </commission_write>
                <commission_read>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_read</use>
                    </connection>
                </commission_read>
            </resources>
        </global>
    </config>
```

Observer.php path app/code/local/Npm/Commission/Model

```
<?php
class Npm_Commission_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
    public function calculate_commission($observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        if (!$order) {
            return $this;
        }
        //die('sales_order_place_after');
         Mage::log('sales_order_place_after');
        //$params = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder;
         Mage::log(print_r($order->getData('increament_id'),true));
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($params);die();
    }
}
```

etc/modules files Npm_Commission.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Npm_Commission>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Npm_Commission>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

rather then you die you `Mage::log('testing');`

Follow the below code

```
<?php
class Npm_Commission_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer
{
    public function saveorder($observer)
    {
        Mage::log('sales_order_place_after');
        $params = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParams();
        Mage::log(print_r($params,true));
    }
```

Make you have enable log in Magento. `system >> Configuration >> Developer >> Log`.

To check your data `var/log`.